# Print aLine with the first 'c' 'C' 'd' or 'D' removed

Tags: java, string, indexof

I am trying to Print aLine with the first instance 'c' 'C' 'd' or 'D' removed. However, I am limited to using ONLY String's indexOf, charAt, length, compareTo, toUpperCase, toLowerCase, trim, equals, equalsIgnoreCase and substring methods. Assume you can enter whatever string you'like.

I have achieved removing 'c'. However if there is a 'd' before the 'c', it still removes the 'c'. I have tried establishing indexes of the letters. I have tried using if statements as well as nested if statements within while and for loops. The results are the same.

```
int c = aLine.indexOf('c');
int upperC = aLine.indexOf('C');
int d = aLine.indexOf('d');
int upperD = aLine.indexOf('D');

for (int i = 0; i < aLine.length(); i++) {
    if (c >= 0 || upperC >= 0 || d >= 0 || upperD >= 0) {
        if (c >= 0) {
            String string1 = aLine.substring(0, c);
            String string2 = aLine.substring(c + 1, length);
            System.out.println(string1 + string2);
            break;
        } else if (upperC >= 0) {
            String string1 = aLine.substring(0, upperC);
            String string2 = aLine.substring(upperC + 1, length);
            System.out.println(string1 + string2);
            break;
        } else if (d >= 0) {
            String string1 = aLine.substring(0, d);
            String string2 = aLine.substring(d + 1, length);
            System.out.println(string1 + string2);
            break;
        } else if (upperD >= 0) {
            String string1 = aLine.substring(0, upperD);
            String string2 = aLine.substring(upperD + 1, length);
            System.out.println(string1 + string2);
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("The original String has no leading or trailing whitespace.");
            break;
        }
```

I am trying to get the first instance of either c C d or D to be removed , then print the string with the removed char. Please advise. I am not sure how to approach this.

Comment: Loop over every character, adding each char to a `StringBuilder` until you come across a `c`, `d`, `C`, or `D`. Once you find it, you can skip that index via `continue` & allow the loop to add the rest of the characters. The `StringBuilder` will then contain the original string, but with the first occurrence of upper/lowercase C or D removed. `StringBuilder` is only there to reduce object creation - you can do this without `StringBuilder` by simply concatenating.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I was not allowed to use StringBuilder.

Comment: You don't have to use `StringBuilder` - it's just for optimization, not to ease. You could simply `+=` to concatenate it to an existing string. It's just that anytime you concatenate, you *are* creating a `StringBuilder`, so technically your code is already using `StringBuilder`. However, my suggestion can easily be achieved without explicitly using a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep it simple:

```
for (int i = 0; i < aLine.length(); i++) {
    char c = aLine.charAt(i);
    if (c == 'c' || c == 'C' || c == 'd' || c == 'D') {
        if (i > 0) System.out.print(aLine.substring(0, i));
        if (i+1 < aLine.length()) System.out.print(aLine.substring(i+1));
        System.out.println();
        break;
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. first two print statements are `print`, not `println`
2. second substring uses form with only start index
3. println is used after both parts of string are printed

Comment: Thank you @Ilya Bursov. Ya I was doing too much. This is much more streamline and effective.

Answer (score 0):

you must compare wich one is first.

Lets say your word is "DCvsMarvel"

in this case D is 0 and C is 1.

so insted of 
if (c >= 0) {

it should include the condition

if (c >= 0 && (C < D || D < 0)) {

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

another simpler solution is to check every char of the string in order and once you find one that fills one of the conditions, do the thing and break. For this aproach do not use the indexOf at the begining

Answer (score 0):

To avoid looking for both uppercase and lowercase, you should create a lowercase copy of `aLine` - You're only worried about the type of letter, not the capitalization of the letter.

```
String aLine = ...;
String lowered = aLine.toLowercase();
```

You'd then loop over the characters of `lowered`.

- If no letters had been skipped yet AND the letter is either `c` or `d`, set a `boolean skipped` to true.
- Otherwise, add the letter to a new `String` (or `StringBuilder` if allowed) which will contain the result, or using `continue` to skip over.

In code:

```
boolean skipped = false;
String result = "";
for(int i = 0; i < lowered.length(); i++) {
    char letter = lowered.charAt(i);

    if(!skipped && (letter == 'c' || letter = 'd')) {
        skipped = true;
    } else {
        result += letter;
    }
}
```

You would then print `result`.